# Primary key of AspNetUsers as foreign of another table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreign-keys, asp.net-identity

I am designing a employee table where I want primary Key of AspNetUsers to be the foreign key i.e the `Id` Column. How do I do this? So far I have tried this. Don't know if this right or wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

```
[Key,DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int HumanResourceId { get; set; } 

    //foreign key of userid
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser appuser { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(30),Index]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string MiddleName { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(25)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(10), Index(IsUnique = true)]
    public string MobileNumber { get; set; }

    [Required, DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "ntext")]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Gender { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime? HireDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime? Date_from { get; set; }

    public DateTime? Date_to { get; set; }

    public bool Active { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have both `UserId` and `AppUser` properties on your entity.

All you need is the `AppUser` property and in your `DbContext` you can specify the mapping as follow:

```
[Table("AspNetUsers")] 
public class ApplicationUser
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser AppUser { get; set; }
}

public class DbContext : System.Data.Entity.DbContext
{
    public DbContext()
        : base("name=DbContext")
    { }

    public IDbSet<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }
    public IDbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
            .HasRequired(x => x.AppUser)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(m => m.MapKey("UserId")); // Name of you FK column
    }
}
```

**Note 1**: in fact, you should avoid having both properties, because you could end up with data integrity issue (by this I mean you will need to ensure UserId and AppUser.UserId are always the same).

**Note 2**: make sure your user Id is a `int` and not a `string` for better performance.

Comment: How this is connected to AspNetUsers table? i want `id` of that table to be foreign key of another table.

Comment: You can use data annotation to tell Entity Framework which table the entity class maps to. I've updated my example accordingly. Alternatively, you can rename your class to have the same same as the table - this way, you won't need the `Table` annotation.

Comment: `AspNetUsers` is the table which is created when using default authentication in MVC 5 using VS 2013 which uses `AspNet.Identity 2.0`. I want to link with the PK of this table to another table as foreign key. I think you didn't understand my question.